# Convert CAP_FIRST Function from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, function

A couple of years ago, I found this CAP_FIRST function for MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR MID(input,i,1) = '-' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

I have used this function extensively to convert people's names to proper capitalization for reports, like so:

```
UPDATE DataImport
    SET FirstName = CAP_FIRST(FirstName);

UPDATE DataImport
    SET LastName = CAP_FIRST(LastName);
```

Now I am migrating to PostgreSQL, and need this same functionality there. Do I need to convert this function to PostgreSQL, or is there a better way to get the same results? If I do need to convert, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that PostgreSQL has a builtin function `initcap()` that does this for me like so:

```
UPDATE DataImport
    SET FirstName = initcap(FirstName);

UPDATE DataImport
    SET LastName = initcap(LastName);
```